# Finding a TURN server VM image

Tags: amazon-web-services, webrtc

A WebRTC Google developer says:

> But the thing I would really recommend is the long name    but really
>   good product: rfc5766-turn-server   which has Amazon VM images you can
>   just take,   download and deploy into the cloud   and you've got your
>   TURN server provisioned for    all your users right there

[Here is the tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p2HzZkd2A40&feature=youtu.be&t=1313) where he makes the statement.

But I was unable to find any downloadable Amazon VM image of
**rfc5766-turn-server** and my questions in the google discussion groups did not get answers.

So if any one knows where to download these Amazon VM images, please give me the link.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell the rfc-5766 project [has moved](https://code.google.com/p/rfc5766-turn-server/) a [couple of times](https://github.com/coturn/rfc5766-turn-server/). And is now developed here:

https://github.com/coturn/coturn

On the downloads page under versions you'll find [these instructions](http://turnserver.open-sys.org/downloads/v4.4.5.4/turnserver-4.4.5.4-amazon-aws-ec2-x86_64.txt):

> Current Amazon TURN Server public AMI: ami-65252855. This image is
>   available in US West (Oregon) region:
>
> search by "coturn" string or by the AMI name.
>
> Below is the README.txt file included into AMI's ec2-user home
>   directory, for information.